# Manually trying to start AR Core XR Loader, but its Subsystems won't start?

Tags: unity, mobile, virtual-reality, augmented-reality

I'm trying to implement that in **one scene** I start the **Google Cardboard XR Loader**, and in the **other scene** I start the **AR Core/AR Kit XR Loader**.

This is how I start the loader required for the scene:

```
 var init = XRLoaderToBeLoaded.Initialize();
 var start = XRLoaderToBeLoaded.Start();
 //  (and deinit+stop them when leaving the scene)
```

Both XR Loaders are **initialized and started successfully**, they return **true**.

With **Google Cardboard everything works fine**.

With **AR Core** I make the **AR Session active** after the XR Loader is fully started (I even tried waiting 5 seconds), but it says basically that **no AR Subsystems are available**.

> No active UnityEngine.XR.ARSubsystems.XRCameraSubsystem is available.
> Please ensure that a valid loader configuration exists in the XR
> project settings.
>
> No active UnityEngine.XR.ARSubsystems.XRSessionSubsystem is available.
> Please ensure that a valid loader configuration exists in the XR
> project settings.
>
> No active UnityEngine.XR.ARSubsystems.XRPlaneSubsystem is available.
> Please ensure that a valid loader configuration exists in the XR
> project settings.
>
> No active UnityEngine.XR.ARSubsystems.XRRaycastSubsystem is available.
> Please ensure that a valid loader configuration exists in the XR
> project settings.
>
> No active UnityEngine.XR.ARSubsystems.XRAnchorSubsystem is available.
> Please ensure that a valid loader configuration exists in the XR
> project settings.
>
> No active UnityEngine.XR.XRInputSubsystem is available. Please ensure
> that a valid loader configuration exists in the XR project settings.

This is the stacktrace for these errors:

```
UnityEngine.XR.ARFoundation.SubsystemLifecycleManager`3:GetActiveSubsystemInstance()
UnityEngine.XR.ARFoundation.SubsystemLifecycleManager`3:EnsureSubsystemInstanceSet()
UnityEngine.XR.ARFoundation.SubsystemLifecycleManager`3:OnEnable()
```

It seems that for some reason **XRLoader.Start() doesn't start (all?) the Subsystems it needs**.

I tried starting them with `XRGeneralSettings.Instance.Manager.StartSubsystems();` and it indeed **started the subsystems**! Now AR works as well!

But the problem is that this method always starts the **subsystems of the first loader in the loader list.**

So when I enter **Google Cardboard VR... AR Core subsystems start up!**

Which doesn't seem to cause any obvious issues right now, but it's better to be cautious: they shouldn't be running in VR for sure.

Any idea how could I solve this issue in a nice way? Is this a design flaw in the XR Management Kit? Am I misunderstanding something? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Turns out that there is a bug in the package itself.**

Previously it seemed straightforward to just

- 1. **Reorder the list** of `activeLoaders` in the Manager so that my desired loader is the first element in the list.
- 2. Thus **I can use the methods of** `XRGeneralSettings.Instance.Manager` to manage the lifecycle of the chosen loader because it always use the **first loader** in the `activeLoaders` list:

  - `InitializeLoader()`,
  - `StartSubsystems()`,
  - `StopSubsystems()`
  - and `DeinitalizeLoader()`.

This is how I reordered the list, but `TrySetLoaders(`) always **failed to reorder the list**, it returned false.

```
private bool MoveLoaderToFrontOfLoaderList(XRLoader loader)
{
    var reorderedLoaders = new List<XRLoader>(Manager.activeLoaders);
    reorderedLoaders.Remove(loader);
    reorderedLoaders.Insert(0, loader);
    return Manager.TrySetLoaders(reorderedLoaders);
}
```

**Turns out the package has a bug:**

- **currently m_RegisteredLoaders is never populated.**
- While `TryAddLoader()` (thus `TrySetLoaders()` as well) checks whether the **loader is registered or not**.
- This means that **runtime modification of the active loaders is not possible** right now.

Here's a class which fixes this issue by populating `m_RegisteredLoaders`:

```
public static class XRGeneralSettingsFix
{
    [RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethod(RuntimeInitializeLoadType.AfterAssembliesLoaded)]
    private static void UpdateRegisteredLoadersList()
    {
        var xrSettingsManager = XRGeneralSettings.Instance.Manager;
        var bindings = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic;
    
        var registeredLoadersField = xrSettingsManager.GetType().GetField("m_RegisteredLoaders", bindings);
        var registeredLoaders = registeredLoadersField.GetValue(xrSettingsManager) as HashSet<XRLoader>;
        
        if (registeredLoaders.Count == 0)
        {
            foreach (var activeLoader in xrSettingsManager.activeLoaders)
            {
                registeredLoaders.Add(activeLoader);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Sources and the issues themselves:**

- Here is the issue reported in detail and also hacks/workarounds: https://forum.unity.com/threads/xrmanagersettings-trysetloaders-doesnt-work-at-runtime.1210000/
- Here's the bug report created by the reporter: https://fogbugz.unity3d.com/default.asp?1408435_6emra084bpmhk9lg
- And here's the actual, active, official issue: https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/xr-xrmanagersettings-dot-trysetloaders-doesnt-work-at-runtime